# Opening new tab without moving to it

Tags: javascript, jsf-2

I need to open a tab with a new URL from JSF via Javascript. The problem is that I don't know how to open it without moving to this newly opened tab. In other words, I want to open a new tab, but stay on my current page.

here is my JSF code:

```
<h:commandButton value="#{appRes['xyz']}" action="#{someBean.downloadFromDetails()}"
    rendered="#{someBean.isDownloadAvailableOnDetails()}" onclick="showUrl();" onblur="location.reload();"/>
```

and here is my Javascript code:

```
function showUrl() {
    window.open('http://www.stackoverflow.com');
}
```

Comment: Don't think that's possible. How and *if* a tab (or a new window) is opened is the decision of the browser.

Comment: On second thought: it'll require some severe hackery but do google for `z-lock` and `window features`.

Answer (score 0):

This is my idea...

```
function showUrl() {
  window.open(window.location);
  window.location='http://www.stackoverflow.com';
}
```

Comment: I see what you want to do, but issuing a new GET request to the current page might not suffice to restore the current page in the new window.